# Is there a way to output the status of dd (on OS X) during the copy process?

Tags: linux, macos, dd

I am using dd to copy iso images to a thumb drive. Is there a way to output the status of dd during the copy process?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you're using OS X, you can press CTRL-T and it will give you a progress update.

Comment: so simple, i wonder why everyone chooses some complex command line wizardry over this

Comment: Mostly because this is OS X/BSD specific, I think.

Answer (score 3):

You can use any command line technique genially available to any *nix user.  There are loads of examples:

1. [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/215505/how-do-you-monitor-the-progress-of-dd)
2. http://pfynotes.blogspot.com/2011/05/monitoring-progress-of-dd-on-osx.html
3. [command line fu](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/1868/watch-the-progress-of-dd)

They all basically lump into one of two categories: send a kill signal (like CTRL-T) or pipe the output through a viewer like `pv`.  I would only recommend `pv` only if you already use MacPorts or HomeBrew.  Simplest example:

```
dd if=file.iso | pv | dd of=/dev/sda3
```

If you have more than 1 file to transfer & also want % complete and and ETA, then you have to provide pv the size of the stream it's watching. You can provide the size of a directory tree as

```
 `SIZE=$(du -sb . | awk '{print $1}')`
```

or an entire file system as

```
 `SIZE=$(df -B1 /dev/sda1 | tail -n1 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f2)`
```

and then pass the size in to `pv` as:

```
dd if=file.iso | pv -s $SIZE | dd of=/dev/sda3
```